# Web-Based Chart Designer

Tags: visualization

Edit:  I noticed that there have been 40 views, but no responses.  Have I asked for too much? Does anyone have any thoughts or points that are responsive to part of what I am looking for?

I am looking for a software library (open source or commercial) for my company that meets the following specifications. A bit of background first.

My company provides cloud-based software that, among other things, allows users to create ad hoc database tables, similar to SharePoint lists, and store any type of data there.  Assume, for the sake of argument, that the data can be accessed through a regular SQL query, against either a table or view.

We want to give our users the ability to visualize the data stored in these ad hoc tables by creating their own charts.  Our end users will not have any technical abilities and no coding should be required to make this possible.

Our software uses java on the backend.  Clients access the software thru a browser and typically no plug-ins or add-ons are required.

Here is what I am looking for:

- A library that can create a very broad range of charts (pie, bar, etc.), not just 1 or 2 kinds, and fairly complex versions of those charts.
- Whether the charts are created on the backend (in java) or on the front end (using javascript) does not matter.
- The end user should be able to use a wizard to design the chart.  This includes not just what type of chart and the various chart options (labels, colors, etc.), but also what data fields will be used to construct each part of the chart.  For example, the end user might select a pie chart, then select a specific data source (e.g., Store Sales), and from the data source they can select the columns that will be used as the pie dimension (the slices) and the pie measure (the size of each slice). This does not necessarily require that the library have access to the data source, as the fields in the data source and the datatype of each could be sent to the library (be it in java or javascript).
- Finally, assuming the data is stored as a regular table or can be accessed as a SQL view, once the fields have been selected and the various aggregations defined to create the chart, the library should write the actual SQL code that will be required to query the underlying data.  The end users cannot be expected to write the SQL code themselves.

I believe there are some SharePoint add-ons that will write the necessary queries to pull data out of a SharePoint list to create the charts.  Something similar to that, but not SharePoint-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark,

I'll try and answer this to the best of my knowledge (Disclosure: I'm the co-founder & CEO of [FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com) - where we make JavaScript charting components).

I've split my answer into 2 parts:

1. How to find a charting component for your web application?
2. How to build the UI for end-users to modify the charts created by these libraries?

There are three ways to add charting capabilities to your web application.

**Using server-side charting libraries**

First is to use platform-specific charting libraries that accept data on server through their APIs, create images to represent the chart, and then stream these images. Examples of such components are Telerik (.NET, paid), Infragistics (.NET, paid), ComponentArt (.NET, paid), ChartFX (Java, .NET, paid), Steema (.NET, paid), pChart (PHP, free), jPGraph, and a whole bunch of them.

The advantage of using such components are:

- Mature libraries offer a huge variety of chart types
- Since the charts are generated as images, they work *everywhere*, including mobile devices
- The look & feel always stays the same, again by the virtue of charts rendered as images
- If just one or two charts are served per user across entire application, lesser bandwidth is used compared to client-side libraries which could range from 50-500KB in size, but get cached thereafter

Disadvantages are:

- Considerable resources are used at server-side when generating charts as images. More so for applications that have many concurrent users
- Interactivity and animation offered by the charts are very limited, as there's only so much you can do with images
- They are technology specific. So if you're using a library for ASP.NET, if/when you move to Java, you'll have to switch to a different library, and hence the look, feel and featureset would differ.

**Using hosted charting APIs**

Second option is to use hosted charting libraries that take in data over querystring/REST API and return chart image back to your application. Examples would be old Google Charting API.

Advantages of this are:

- You do not need to host the charting library, and hence all maintenance and upgrade issues are managed by them
- When you change your technology stack, the charts are still delivered by the same service and hence look & feel are same

Disadvantages:

- Such services do NOT offer a variety of chart types
- Confidential data needs to be transferred over HTTP outside your servers to such providers
- Limitations on amount of data that can be sent over querystring
- Again, charts cannot be interactive, as they are images

**Client-side charting using JavaScript, CSS, Flash, Silverlight or Java applets**

The third and last option is to use client-side charting libraries written in either JavaScript/HTML5, Pure CSS, Flash, Java applets or Microsoft Silverlight. Considering the fact that iOS devices do not support and proprietary plugins, Flash, Java and Silverlight based plugins do not work on iPads and iPhones. So you can safely to ignore them. Pure CSS components are very light-weight and can be used for very basic visualizations.

That finally brings us to JavaScript/HTML5 based charting components. There are a whole bunch of JavaScript charting libraries, both free and paid. I've listed some of them below:

Paid: FusionCharts Suite XT (JavaScript), HighCharts, amcharts, AnyChart, Jqplot, ZingCharts, Wijmo, TeeChart, Sencha Touch Charts, RGpraph, Kendo UI DataViz, JSCharts, Arcadia Charts, jQChart, EJSChart, emprisejs, techoctave

Free: FusionCharts Free (Flash), Google Chart Tools, Yahoo UI components, Flot, Milkchart, Moochart, protovis, graphael, elycharts, smootiecharts, dhtmlxchart, grafico, canvasjs, dygraphs, thejit, awesomechartjs,  jchartFX. More free components based on d3.js for data visualization: xcharts, nvd3, rickshaw, cubism.js, Dc.js, xkcd, graphene

Now, given the number of components available, the questions you need to ask yourself when narrowing done for a charting component should include:

- What chart types would you need - now and in the future? If you need very basic charts like column, pie etc., most of these libraries fit the bill. But if you need even slightly advanced charts like Pareto or Funnel, most of the components do not offer such charts.
- How important is for you to have the charts rendered on maximum number of devices and older browsers like IE6? Many open-source libraries just use SVG for rendering, thereby not having support for IE6,7,8 (which 6% of the world still uses).
- Can you use the part of your product where you implement data visualization as a USP during demos? If yes, how important is the look & feel of the charting component to you?
- Are you looking to spend considerable amount of time tweaking the charts for basic features? For example, many open-source libraries enable tool-tips upon writing additional code, or the fact that if you've >25 data points on chart, x-axis label overlapping needs to be taken care of by you. Or, do you want these capabilities out of the box, so that you can focus on your application and business logic?
- How important is it for you to be able to customize each and every feature of the chart, including cosmetics? For example, do you need to be able to render the charts in 3D, customize how the number gets formatted, control gradients etc.?
- Do you want a component with an exhaustive documentation and real-life business demos so that you can get started easily, or are you ok with minimal docs and learning by experimentation which could take a lot time?
- Is it important for you to get personalized support when something doesn't work as expected, or are you ok with posting on public forums and not having an SLA for a reply/fix?

Hoping that this information would help you choose a charting component for your web application, let me address the second question: Is there a component that comes with a client-side wizard for end-users to design the chart?

For the client-side charting libraries, the short answer is NO. Because, it ties the client-side library to a particular server-side technology for data persistence, and secondly not many users have need for it.

Some server-side libraries (Dundas used to have this capability) do provide this capability, though not all features of the chart can be customized at client-side.

That being said, many developers have created such wizards for use by non technical users. For example, at FusionCharts, we have created wizard for SharePoint which is called Collabion (see www.collabion.com), and PowerPoint which is called oomfo (www.oomfo.com). While these are not open source, we would be happy to share code of these, if you find them relevant.

Another option is to use an open-source BI component (like Pentaho, JasperSoft etc.) that have charting components in-built and also provide a wizard for end-users. However, they could require considerable server resources per user, and are time-taking to install and maintain.

Hope I've been able to answer your questions.

Comment: Pallav, thanks.  (I apologize for not responding sooner, as I was traveling.)  By coincidence, I had reached out to your company, as I had identified FusionCharts and Collabion as possible solutions.  Unfortunately, as I discovered, Collabion only works for SharePoint and FusionCharts does not have a wizard.  Given that Collabion can pull data from virtually any data source, it might be useful to make that feature available from platforms other than SharePoint, or to add that wizard capability to your other products.  And thank you for the product recommendations, even for your competitors.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a "build vs. buy" question. I'm interested to know if you have looked into comprehensive business intelligence tool like Tableau, qlikview, jDashboard, or LogiAnalytics?

Of course buying a pre-built solution will come down to constraints- can your vendor work with you on these? Or allow you to build minimal add-ons to address them? This might achieve many of your application's goals but have a higher upfront licensing cost.

Purchasing a visualization library or downloading an open source lib would provide one of the many materials you need to build the application you've described. This would have lower licensing costs but require building out the rest of your requirements around it.

The decision you need to make is whether you have the patience and ability required to juggle multiple libraries and handle custom coding, or whether you would be willing to pay for a complete solution that satisfies most but not necessarily ALL of your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement seems to be two-fold from my perspective. I would share my views, though I am not sure if it will help you.

1. You need a charting component that is diverse in nature, easily configurable, robust to extreme tinkering by users and looks good even in worst case scenario. (I assumed many items here since it is evident that users would be creating charts and thus it can be highly far-fetched.)
2. A visual editor (preferably wizard-style), that can be used to create and configure every aspect of such charts from exiting data sources.
3. Since your application is for creating and store custom data sources (as far as I could figure,) using a BI tool as overlay makes less sense since the nature of data is too flexible to conform to any source standards.

If my basic analysis is correct, then the following is my advise on a respective bases:

1. For such a comprehensive requirement, you would need charting solution that specialises 
   in visualisation and is a visualisation component taking care of your charting needs.

   The only component that I see that meets your requirement is
   [FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/). The reason being that FusionCharts is designed to
   cater to enterprise customers with high fault-tolerance on input and
   yet look appealing. (I can elaborate with examples or you can lookup the website 
   http://www.fusioncharts.com/.)
2. Sadly, there is no such component that comes inherently paired with such a capable 
   visualisation front-end. This primarily because most charting solutions provider caters 
   to consumers whose use-cases involve the chart generation to be on their own end.

   You do have [Dundas Chart Builder](http://support2.dundas.com/Default.aspx?article=1193) - which IMHO is not web-based and 
   [jsCharts chart editor](http://www.jscharts.com/template) - whose visualisation front-end is not as comprehensive as 
   your needs and I am not sure if they sell the editor.

   Having said that, there is another product from FusionCharts called [Collabion](http://www.collabion.com/).
   The product uses FusionCharts to render charts and connects SharePoint data sources.
   The interesting part is the visual chart builder that it has. It allows you to fully
   customise the appearance and functionalities of FusionCharts and configuration of 
   data sources. Visit http://www.collabion.com/ and you can check out the screenshots.

   Collabion is primarily intended for deployment on MicroSoft stack (SharePoint), but 
   your requirement is on Java. IMHO, if you go to that length, you can run an instance 
   of SharePoint and communicate the process. (Just thinking aloud.)

Comment: Shamasis, thanks for your response. I'm not sure how technically feasible it would be to run an instance of SharePoint and have that integrate sufficiently in our environment so that we could utilize Collabion. As I mentioned to Pallav, given that Collabion connects to non-SharePoint data sources, it would be great to make its many wonderful features available independent of SharePoint, possibly by adding them to FusionChart?

Comment: @MarkSalamon I understand. I would revert if I see anything around. :)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, FusionchartXT matchs your requirement, but you need a web-based FusionchartXT editor too. It must allow your customers optionally configure their charts attributes, cosmetics, dateset, and trend lines, just like this: http://www.crossui.com/FCEditor/.